# Python & Matplotlib - table changes size on 2nd loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a small digital-signage app that displays a barchart of some data, with a table containing the same data below it. It's to run continuously in a loop, in fullscreen and in the real app will pull fresh data from a database each time (this part already works fine).

The problem is that the Barchart and Table display absolutely fine the first time the loop runs:[First loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTLBb.jpg)

but on the second, and subsequent loops the table data is condensed into roughly half the vertical frame, with the previous view observable behind it: [2nd and subsequent loops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwDbo.jpg)

Here's a subset of the code, to demonstrate the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Want a bigger barchart on the top, with smaller table of data below
fig, (ax, ax_table) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, gridspec_kw = dict(height_ratios = [7,1]))

ax_table.axis('off') # removes the extraneous graph axis

mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle() # And run it fullscreen

while(True):
    test_data = [["A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000], [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]]
    
    dfcon = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
    dfcon = dfcon.transpose()
    print('dfcon = ')
    print(dfcon)
    
    ax.cla()    # clear the current axes (the bar chart part)
    ticks = np.arange(len(dfcon))
           
    bar_width = 0.4
    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.margins(x=0.01) # the 0.1 we need either side divided by the number of elements to align with the table
    b1 = ax.bar(ticks , dfcon[1], width= -(bar_width), align = 'edge') # negative bar width figure here aligns to left of tick mark
    b2 = ax.bar(ticks , dfcon[3], width= bar_width, align = 'edge')
    
    ax.plot(kind='bar')
        
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='green')
    ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
    ax.set_ylabel('Time')
    
    descriptors = ('Tag', 'Target', 'Actual', 'Small #')
    ax_table = plt.table(cellText=test_data, rowLabels = descriptors, loc='center')
    ax_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    ax_table.set_fontsize(12)
       
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    fig.show()
    
    plt.pause(10)
```

I've tried various things to maintain the correct table cell size/position but can't work out why it's resizing and overwriting the previous table, rather than refreshing it.

Any thoughts, suggestions gratefully received.

Tried: populating the table from a dataframe that is declared as new (test_data = pd.DataFrame() ) within the loop.
Have tried ax_table.clear(), ax_table.clf(), ax_table.scale(1,1), ax_table.axis('off') again within the main loop - although some of these generated errors.

Edit - here's the working code after JohanC's suggestion:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Want a bigger barchart on the top, with smaller table of data below
fig, (ax, ax_table) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, gridspec_kw = dict(height_ratios = [7,1]))

mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle() # And run it fullscreen

while(True):

    test_data = [["A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000], [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]]
    
    dfcon = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
    dfcon = dfcon.transpose()
    print('dfcon = ')
    print(dfcon)
    
    ax.cla()    # clear the current axes (the bar chart part)
    ax_table.cla() # clear the current axes (the table part)
    ticks = np.arange(len(dfcon))
           
    bar_width = 0.4
    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.margins(x=0.01) # the 0.1 we need either side divided by the number of elements to align with the table
    b1 = ax.bar(ticks , dfcon[1], width= -(bar_width), align = 'edge') # negative bar width figure here aligns to left of tick mark
    b2 = ax.bar(ticks , dfcon[3], width= bar_width, align = 'edge')
    
    ax.plot(kind='bar')
        
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='green')
    ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
    ax.set_ylabel('Time')
    
    descriptors = ('Tag', 'Target', 'Actual', 'Small #')

    ax_table.cla()
    ax_table.axis('off') # removes the extraneous graph axis
    
    # create a new plt.table to be added to the axes
    tb = plt.table(cellText=test_data, rowLabels = descriptors, bbox = [0,0,1,1.5], loc='center') # added bounding-box to ensure table is shown correct size.
    tb.auto_set_font_size(False)
    tb.set_fontsize(12)
        
    ax_table.add_table(tb)
   
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    fig.show()
    
    plt.pause(10)
```

Comment: [`plt.table`s docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html) seem to suggest to use `ax_table.add_table(...)` instead of `plt.table` if you want to reuse the space.  Also note that you are using the variable name `ax_table` for two very different objects. First you use it as an `ax` in `plt.subplots()`. Afterward, you use the same variable name for the `Table` returned by `plt.table(...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much - with your help I'm very nearly there. I have created the plt.table object under a new name and then added it to the ax_table axes:

Comment: Forgot to add JohanC that I still got the issue with the table shrinking in size when it was redrawn on subsequent loops. To fix this I needed to specify the bbox parameter in the table function. It now all works perfectly!

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78001727/edit) your post and change the code there to your latest version?  Usually, there is no need to explicitly add the `bbox` parameters.